# How to check if the for loop is interrupted in Python

Tags: python

Is there any Pythonic way to know if the for loop is interrupted?

I have a very large list, with 100 000 records. I want to loop through all list items but I want to know if there for some reason (for example: if the power is gone, if the battery is empty of for any other reason) the loop is interrupted and didn't come to the end of the list.

Thus for example if I have list as follows:

```
some_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"]
for item in some_list:
    # If it came to item3 and it's interrupted. How can I know that?
    print(item)
```

Comment: *"for example: if the power is gone*: so let's say this happens. What are the means by which you wish to be notified that the loop didn't complete?

Comment: The index counter has to be stored at a persistent storage address. After powering on you can read that address. Real Time Operating Systems deal with issues like this.

Comment: You will need to work with some kind of persistent storage, e.g. a flat file or a database where you can store and retrieve the different states of your process.

Comment: What about creating a file if the loop completes ? Printing in console doesn't seem to be a viable solution if "power is gone" ?

Comment: Why three downvotes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In python, you can use the `for/else` statement. You can add an else statement after a for loop and if break was *not* called, the else statement will  trigger.

You can use this to set a flag that the for loop finished.

**Example:**

```
for i in range(10)
    if i == 10:
        break
else:
    print('the for loop ran without breaking')
```

The above code will print the text 'the for loop ran without breaking', whereas the code below will not.

```
for i in range(10)
    if i == 5:
        break
else:
    print('the for loop ran without breaking')
```

Answer (score 2):

> for example: if the power is gone:

The only way to deal with this is to write the state of the loop to permanent storage at regular intervals.

You can keep writing the item you're currently processing to a file.

Then, you can check that file to see if it reached the last element after your computer restarts.

Something like:

```
    file_path = 'some_file_path'
    with open(file_path, 'a') as progress_file:
        some_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"]
        for item in some_list:
            progress_file.write(item + '\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `enumerate` on the list, then check the index which should be equals to `len(the_list) - 1`.

```
for idx, el in enumerate(the_list):
    # todo
if idx != len(the_list)-1:
    print('Interrupted')
```

Comment: This doesn't cover the case when you would lose power

Answer (score 1):

You have misconception regarding what is **interrupt**. Interrupts are used to signal a program something. They are part of your program.

What you mean by power-off or a program crash for some reason, is kind of **disaster** situations. 
The only way to do it is using a **flag**, which needs to be on permanent medium (such as disk, database, etc) in case of something bad happens.

Using `for/else` or `break` statements won't work here; if the loop is running and the power is shut off, the code won't reach there.

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w', bufsize=0) as f:       
    f.write('in progress')
    some_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"]
        for item in some_list:
            # If it came to item3 and it's interrupted. How can I know that?
            print(item)
    f.write('done')
```

The above code will *sign* a file that it started - *in progress* - and another sign once its done. If you see just the first sign, the loop never finished as expected.

the **bufsize** argument makes the buffer flush immediately. 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line buffered, any other positive value means use a buffer of (approximately) that size.

Comment: vinny there's an indentation error after your 'for; statement in the second last line

Comment: what if there is a power cut before the file gets written , but the loop completes ? May be update the file for every loop run

Comment: @BloomBlack I've added bufsize 0, so every call to write is flushed and not buffered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if the loop is interrupted, it will print `'interrupted'`

```
some_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"]
try:
    for item in some_list:
        print(some_list[some_list.index(item)+1])
except:
    print('interrrupted')
```

Comment: I do not want to interrupt the loop manually. I want to know if the loop is interrupted for whatever reason

Comment: if the loop is interrupted unexpectedly, you will see an exception.

Comment: @sudonym Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Using an extra variable you can achieve this :

```
some_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"]
flag = False
for item in some_list:
    # If it came to item3 and it's interrupted. How can I know that?
    if item==some_list[2]:
        flag=True
        break
```

Checking value of `flag` variable you can check whether the loop is interrupted or not.
Note : You can use for/else statement in Python:

```
some_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"]
for item in some_list:
    # If it came to item3 and it's interrupted. How can I know that?
    if item==some_list[2]:
        break
else: #this block will execute if your loop ends without interruption
    print("The loop completed without any interruption)
```